# Site not responding to media query

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I'm using Windows 10, Codeigniter, jQuery and Firefox 43.0.4 although I can't see why that would affect this issue. I want to apply styles to an iPad size window so I'm using this media query:

```
@media only screen
and (min-device-width: 768px)
and (max-width: 1024px)
{
    *{color:#ff0000 !important;}
}
```

as a test that should turn all text red but it's not working in Firefox 43.0.4 (or Chrome etc). I'm also using the Web Developer extension to set the portal to the correct size. I've used the head section metatag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Probably obvious but I can't see it and I've used media queries before. This is driving me nuts and I would be grateful for any suggestions as to where I'm going wrong.

Comment: @media only screen and (min-width: 768px and max-width: 1024px) - try this

Comment: @Perkin5, try to create DEMO, that make SO members to help you better

Comment: Just tested it in jsfiddle and your code works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are missing the device prefix, the CSS should be:

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px)  { /* STYLES GO HERE */}
```

You can read more information on [Stephen Gilbert's site](http://stephen.io/mediaqueries/).

Comment: Then it's most likely an issue somewhere else in your CSS or a validation issue on your HTML page.

Comment: Page validates OK and if I move the css 'red text' statement just above the media query it works.

Answer (score 1):

You dont have to use `min-device-width`, just use `min-width`

```
 @media screen and (min-width:768px) and (max-width:1024px) {}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
@media only screen 
and (max-width: 480px),(min-device-width: 768px) 
and (max-device-width: 1024px)
```

Comment: As someone already mentioned, give us full code somewhere like fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ so that we can test it... it is easier to answer.

Comment: Well this is a wedding site I am creating and you can see it at URL http://www.olivierandnatalia.com/site/home. I hope that helps.

Comment: But it seems that it is working, here is screenshot:

http://www.milosev.com/Download/perkin5/perkin.png

I didn't check the code, but probably you have to use different width / height small or bigger depending on your needs...

Comment: Amazing - it must have been some sort of refresh problem. However, I notice that it still doesn't work on my iPad

Comment: Possible, try deleting cash, or if you have Chrome open it in incognito mode. Also, I don't know how big resolution iPad have it can be that it is too big, meaning that you will not see red color, because on iPad width is too big and media query too small....

Comment: Hmm - I cleared the iPad cache and also added                `and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)`             to take account of the fact that it is an iPad 4 but still the media query is not working

Answer (score 0):

I appear to have fixed the problem by using Mathew Riches code above and the reason I didn't recognize this earlier is that, for me, it doesn't work in a resized firefox browser window which has been my testbed of choice. To use the resized browser I need to use:

```
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 768px) 
and (max-width : 1024px)  { /* STYLES GO HERE */}
```

but that doesn't work on my iPad 4. And inciddentally any use of:

```
and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
```

with a pixel ratio of 1 or 2 killed the response on my iPad 4.

So the only way to test has been to upload every change in CSS and check on the iPad itself which is pretty irritating as I normally use my local server for all development.

I then discovered a problem with full-screen background images on the iPad but that is another story...

Many thanks to all contributors for your thoughts and for my purposes I now regard this query as solved.